# How do I submit data to my API in Blazor C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I've written a simple API using MediatR with examples that I have found online. It has a GET and a POST.

The API GET:

```cs
namespace API.Features.My.Queries;

[Route("api/mydata/{myid}")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;
    public MyController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] long myid)
    {
        var response = await _mediator.Send(new MyGet.Request { Id = applicationid });
        return Ok(response);
    }

}
```

In the Blazor page, I am able to call the API GET just fine:

```cs
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var version2 = await _apiservice.GetFromJsonAsync<MyGet>($"api/mydata/{appid}", new CancellationToken());
        data = version2.Data;
        editContext = new(data);
        isLoading = false;
    }
```

But I am having problems understanding how to get the post to work.

The POST:

```cs
namespace API.Features.My.Commands;

[Route("api/mydata")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public MyController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Submit([FromBody] SaveMyInfo info)
    {
        SaveMyInfo.Response response = await _mediator.Send(info);
        return response.Success ? Ok(response) : NotFound(response);
    }
}
```

In my Blazor page, this is how I am trying to POST my changes:

```cs
    private async Task Submit(EditContext context)
    {
        var dto = new SaveMyInfo()
        {
            Data = (MyGet)context.Model
        };
        var responseMessage = string.Empty;
        var version2 = await _apiservice.PostFromJsonAsync<SaveMyInfo>("api/mydata/Submit", dto, new CancellationToken());
        // above gives "Bad Request"
    }
```

The breakpoint on the Server API's Submit is never reached.

I've tried to read up on how to submit to an API, but the examples I find always pass in the string they use to connect, so I am left guessing with how to do that part.

What needs to change so that the POST Submit can be reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI you need to use to call your POST method is `api/mydata` and not `api/mydata/Submit`.

```
await _apiservice.PostFromJsonAsync<SaveMyInfo>("api/mydata", dto, new CancellationToken());
```

If you want it to be `api/mydata/Submit` you need to add `[Route("Submit")]` to the submit method.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Submit")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Submit([FromBody] SaveMyInfo info)
{
    SaveMyInfo.Response response = await _mediator.Send(info);
    return response.Success ? Ok(response) : NotFound(response);
}
```

Or you can change the route attribute on your controller to `[Route("api/mydata/[action]")]`.

Check [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: This seems to be the way, but my *PostFromJsonAsync* is failing. I think it's because my class *SaveMyInfo* contains a list of phone number models that is making the data too big. I've got to figure out a way to categorize my data.

Answer (score 0):

Just using httpclient:

client in BLAZOR:

```
public async Task<AuthResponse> AuthenticateUser(LoginDto loginData)
{
    AuthResponse? returnResponse = null;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var url = $"{_settingsService.GetApiUrlBase()}{ApiRootUrls.AuthenticateUser}";

        var serializedStr = JsonSerializer.Serialize(loginData);

        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(serializedStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string contentStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
            };
            returnResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AuthResponse>(contentStr, options);
        }
    }
    return returnResponse;
}
```

webapi:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Login"), AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<AuthResponse> Login([FromBody] AuthRequest request)
{
    return await _userService.Login(request);
}
```